# expected primary-expression before const, no match for operator[]

Tags: c++

I'm trying to just send my array (grid) of points to my loadGrid function, but it's not working for some reason. Originally it was because I was declaring my grid to be the size of my amountofcolumns and amountofrows variables, so I tried 'fixing' that by declaring the grid to be 100 in both dimensions so I could test the rest of the program, but it still doesn't work. In the line where I call loadGrid, I get the error "expected primary-expression before const", and down when I try to assign a value to a grid value's variable and then print it, I get "no match for operator[]". Any advice?
Here's my code

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

int amountofcolumns = 0;
int amountofrows = 0;
int readGrid(int argc, char** argv);

class car
{
    int carnumber;
    int xpos;
    int ypos;
    int dxvel;
    int dyvel;
    int maxspeed = 5;
    int currentspeed;
};

struct point
{
    int val; //value of the square
    int caroccupied; //what car is on it, 0 if no car
    char given; //what the actual character of the space is
    bool wall; // is the thing a wall?
};

int loadGrid(int argc, char** argv, const point &grid, int amtcol, int amtrow);

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    readGrid(argc, argv);
    cout << "Testing to see if this worked" << endl;
    cout << amountofcolumns << " " << amountofrows;
    point grid[100][100];
    loadGrid(argc, argv, const point &grid, amountofcolumns, amountofrows);
}

int loadGrid(int argc, char** argv, const point &grid, int amtcol, int amtrow)
{
    grid[1][3].val = 51;
    cout << grid[1][3].val;
}

int readGrid(int argc, char** argv)
{
    //This code determines how many lines there are
    //in the grid, and how many columns there are.
    string linelengthbeta;
    string lineamountbeta;
    int counter = 0;
    std::string current_exec_name = argv[0];
    std::string filename;
    if (argc > 1) {
        filename = argv[1];
    }
    cout << filename;
    ifstream infile(filename.c_str());
    while(!infile.eof())
    {
        getline(infile, lineamountbeta);
        counter++;
    }
    amountofcolumns = linelengthbeta.length();
    cout << amountofcolumns;
    amountofrows = counter + 1;
    cout << amountofrows;
    infile.close();

    return amountofrows;
    return amountofcolumns;
}
```

Comment: Indentation? Is that the old fashion?

Comment: The arg type in LoadGrid for grid is wrong: const point &grid,

Comment: `return amountofrows; return amountofcolumns;` You'll rant to pay attention to your compiler warnings here!

Comment: yeah, two return statements does bode ill for the code being correct.

Comment: I haven't gotten to the part where I'm implementing the car class yet, but I wanted to include my entire code. I'll go back and fix those two returns later, but I'm not sure what you mean by scoping. I don't know another way on how to retrieve the values I need from the text file.

Comment: @JoJoBya: You really need to include a [Short, Self Contained, **Correct** (Compilable), Example](http://sscce.org/). We can't be expected to distinguish between parts of your code **you know are broken** and those which aren't.

Comment: I apologize, I'm very tired and I should have put more time into writing the question and specified which portions worked and which did not; I'll be sure to do this next time I post a question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to your LoadGrid  function signature you are passing in a single point `const point &grid`, but according to your code, you are passing in a point[100][100].

Switch to this function signature and it works better:

```
int loadGrid(int argc, char** argv, point grid[][100], int amtcol, int amtrow)
```

(call it like: `loadGrid(argc, argv, grid, amountofcolumns, amountofrows)`;)

Comment: Of course, that probably not a signature you really want, but if you want a point **grid signature, you may need to pass in a thing that has been created differently.